# How to exclude a constructor in findbugs?

Tags: java, findbugs

I can exclude a regular method like this in my findbugs-exclude.xml:

```
<Match>
    <Class name="com.my.package.MyClass"/>
    <Method name="calculateSomeValue"/>
    <Bug pattern="CLI_CONSTANT_LIST_INDEX"/>
</Match>
```

But what if I want to ignore the bug pattern being flagged in a constructor?

I've tried

```
<Method name="MyClass"/>
```

and

```
<Method name="new"/>
```

which don't seem to work.

MyClass only defines one constructor.

Comment: Maybe this will works `<Method name="<init>" params="" returns="void" />` I think you have to encode the `<` and `>` but i'm not sure.

Comment: Nice call, I used `<Method name="&lt;init&gt;"/>`. If you want to post as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use this code for exclude constructor

```
<Method name="&lt;init&gt;"/>
```

Comment: This also works with [Spotbugs](https://spotbugs.github.io), the Findbugs successor.